# Debug pipelined Node.js processes

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I have a command that looks basically like so:

```
node --inspect-brk=9229 a.js | node --inspect-brk=54031 b.js
```

When I start this command at the command line, I get this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54031/66c60348-ce22-4acc-9ba3-aa97b8dd1f12
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/59c70b31-8af6-4c99-bdaf-c1a86f49d62b
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

They are hardcoded to listen on different ports, one on the default (9229) the other on 54031.

However, when I debug with Chrome tools, only one Chrome debug window opens and when I try different urls, I cannot get a second debugging session to open.

The url that works is like so:

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/59c70b31-8af6-4c99-bdaf-c1a86f49d62b
```

and if I try pasting this into a new window:

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws://127.0.0.1:54031/66c60348-ce22-4acc-9ba3-aa97b8dd1f12
```

it doesn't work

Comment: By "doesnt work", I mean nothing happens when I load the second url

Comment: What happens if you change `ws://` in the second url to `ws=`?

Comment: Have you tried opening the second Chrome in incognito mode?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws://127.0.0.1:54031/66c60348-ce22-4acc-9ba3-aa97b8dd1f12
```

to

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:54031/66c60348-ce22-4acc-9ba3-aa97b8dd1f12
```

`true&ws://` to `true&ws=`

I too tried this and its working just fine.